# Game Save or All level played for year can be reload?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My laptop is very old, still running Windown XP (mother board support maximum to Window Vista), I intent to upgrade to Window 8 with new computer.

The question is here, after I reinstall the game from the Mahjong server to the new computer, can I continue the game play, or I need to restart all over again. please advise if anyone knew about this, thank you.

Comment: Mahjong is a card game. :D You mean "Mojang".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can move your save files from computer to computer. By default the save files are in `%APPDATA%\.minecraft\saves`, just start `Run..` and type in exactly that. Then copy the folders inside the Explorer window that opens to the new computer (same path - `%APPDATA%\.minecraft\saves`, make sure that minecraft was run at least once on the target computer to generate the folder)/